# Very low random IOPS reported on SSDs

Tags: ssd, performance, speed, benchmarking, samsung-ssd

I have two Samsung SSDs in my computer, an 840 Pro and 860 Evo, reporting very low random IOPS numbers, about 1/5 of the nominal, connected via a SATA3 interface, using an i7-3770K CPU in a P8Z77-V motherboard:
[image: Samsung MAgician]

Please advise.

---

**In response to comments below:**

- > Are AHCI and TRIM enabled?

  Yes
- > Is caching enabled?

  I believe so, but it should not matter since I am benchmarking the drive, not the cache.
- > Is the firmware for both chipset and SSD updated?

  Was updated a while ago, they are old.
- > Have you tried benchmarking using another program or only Samsung Magician?

  CrystalDiskMark 8.0.1 results on default settings:

  - **840 Pro:**

    ```
    [Read]
      SEQ    1MiB (Q=  8, T= 1):   555.696 MB/s [    530.0 IOPS] < 15045.39 us>
      SEQ    1MiB (Q=  1, T= 1):   513.031 MB/s [    489.3 IOPS] <  2040.42 us>
      RND    4KiB (Q= 32, T= 1):    98.627 MB/s [  24078.9 IOPS] <  1290.06 us>
      RND    4KiB (Q=  1, T= 1):    27.112 MB/s [   6619.1 IOPS] <   149.27 us>

    [Write]
      SEQ    1MiB (Q=  8, T= 1):   440.866 MB/s [    420.4 IOPS] < 18900.28 us>
      SEQ    1MiB (Q=  1, T= 1):   486.462 MB/s [    463.9 IOPS] <  2148.58 us>
      RND    4KiB (Q= 32, T= 1):    86.295 MB/s [  21068.1 IOPS] <  1469.22 us>
      RND    4KiB (Q=  1, T= 1):    55.701 MB/s [  13598.9 IOPS] <    71.98 us>
    ```
  - **860 Evo:**

    ```
    [Read]
      SEQ    1MiB (Q=  8, T= 1):   564.342 MB/s [    538.2 IOPS] < 14817.95 us>
      SEQ    1MiB (Q=  1, T= 1):   528.124 MB/s [    503.7 IOPS] <  1983.09 us>
      RND    4KiB (Q= 32, T= 1):   105.485 MB/s [  25753.2 IOPS] <  1201.47 us>
      RND    4KiB (Q=  1, T= 1):    33.266 MB/s [   8121.6 IOPS] <   121.58 us>

    [Write]
      SEQ    1MiB (Q=  8, T= 1):   534.566 MB/s [    509.8 IOPS] < 15597.54 us>
      SEQ    1MiB (Q=  1, T= 1):   498.652 MB/s [    475.6 IOPS] <  2099.09 us>
      RND    4KiB (Q= 32, T= 1):    92.856 MB/s [  22669.9 IOPS] <  1365.49 us>
      RND    4KiB (Q=  1, T= 1):    61.660 MB/s [  15053.7 IOPS] <    64.86 us>
    ```
- > Also, Samsung Magician used to have an option to enable 'RAPID mode' - have you checked if that's enabled?

  RAPID mode is disabled, and since it is just extra RAM caching it should not affect the benchmark.

Comment: Are `AHCI` and `TRIM` enabled? Is caching enabled? Is the firmware for both chipset and SSD updated? Have you tried benchmarking using another program or only Samsung Magician? Also, Samsung Magician used to have an option to enable 'RAPID mode' - have you checked if that's enabled?

Comment: @telometto see my answers in the edited question

Comment: Contact Samsung support, as there isn't anything as an end-user you can actually do to affect IOPS beyond drive firmware, motherboard firmware/disk controller firmware, and SATA cables AFAIK, and considering the low TBW, Samsung support is going to be the likely endpoint since random IOPS should be ~46K - ~58K on a SATA drive when benchmarked via Magician _(keep in mind drives should be benchmarked without intensive programs/user activity in the background)_. Also, RAPID Mode doesn't affect IOPS, just large file transfer speed on the drive it's enabled on to ~3.5GB/s